# Why is my CSS Animation so slow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

My animation works but after 3 DIVs growing, the animation slows my browser down. I tought CSS was the way to go for performant animations?

Here is my Code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="redi" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redii" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="rediii" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="rediv" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redv" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redvi" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redvii" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redviii" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redix" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redx" class="backgroundheart"></div>
    <div id="redxi" class="backgroundheart"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.start{
    animation: grow 10s ease-in;
}
@keyframes grow {
    0% {transform: scale(0.1) rotate(45deg);}
    100% {transform: scale(100) rotate(45deg);}
}
```

CSS To style:

```
.backgroundheart{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin:5px 0px 0px -35px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.backgroundheart:before,.backgroundheart:after { 
position: absolute;
width: 110%;
height: 110%;
content: '';
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-o-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.backgroundheart:before{
bottom: 0px;
left: -60%;
}
.backgroundheart:after{
top: -60%;
right: 0px;
}
   #redi.backgroundheart,#redi.backgroundheart:before,#redi.backgroundheart:after{background: #b71c1c;}
    #redii.backgroundheart,#redii.backgroundheart:before,#redii.backgroundheart:after{ background: #c62828; }
    #rediii.backgroundheart,#rediii.backgroundheart:before,#rediii.backgroundheart:after{ background: #d32f2f; }
#rediv.backgroundheart,#rediv.backgroundheart:before,#rediv.backgroundheart:after{ background: #e53935; }
#redv.backgroundheart,#redv.backgroundheart:before,#redv.backgroundheart:after{ background: #f44336; }
#redvi.backgroundheart,#redvi.backgroundheart:before,#redvi.backgroundheart:after{ background: #ef5350; }
#redvii.backgroundheart,#redvii.backgroundheart:before,#redvii.backgroundheart:after{ background: #e57373; }
#redviii.backgroundheart,#redviii.backgroundheart:before,#redviii.backgroundheart:after{ background: #ef9a9a; }
#redix.backgroundheart,#redix.backgroundheart:before,#redix.backgroundheart:after{ background: #ffcdd2; }
#redx.backgroundheart,#redx.backgroundheart:before,#redx.backgroundheart:after{ background: #ffebee; }
#redxi.backgroundheart,#redxi.backgroundheart:before,#redxi.backgroundheart:after{ background: #fff; }
```

JQuery:

```
$('.backgroundheart').each(function(index, el) {
    i = index * 2000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(el).addClass('start');
    },i)
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because  `i = index * 2000` each div's animation time will increase gradually?

Comment: I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rzxu79s/) but it doesn't really do much. In particular, it doesn't slow my computer down. Nice effect with the scrollbars though.

Comment: I don't think we have the CSS necessary to style the `backgroundheart` elements the way you must have them in your app, but if I style them like little circles it seems to run fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2rzxu79s/6/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the styles..
Somehow it has to do something with the heart shape right? Because your fiddle with the circles work proper Chev...
What's the matter with the hearts?

Comment: Ok, I figured out that it is only Firefox who's messing around and getting slow with the hearts once they get out of the viewport... Do you guys have the same problems or is it just me?